Adjust kerning for garamond math
I would like to adjust the kerning between some glyphs, since imo e.g. '(' and 'f' are typeset way too close.

% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}

\begin{document}
    $(f) (y)$
\end{document}

I found a solution to a similar question here, however I am not sure how to adapt this. What is the "postscript name" of the font? How do I adapt the bottom_right argument?

Off-topic: the minimal class can sometimes be problematic. It is usually better to use standalone or simply article

In ConTeXt this issue is fixed runtime with so-called goodie files. Maybe one can do something similar in LaTeX? Another option is to adapt the font.

@mickep I would like to stay in LuaLaTeX and be platform independent since I have collaborators.

Use the longmath package, eg: $\mmrel(f\frac{1+x^2}{4}\rright) \mmrel(y\rright)$

@yannisl I mean that is basically the same as just define some custom \myleftbracket. This is less readable, more error-prune and uncomfortable, if I want to switch between fonts.
